# Php - Extract zip file with log in a *.csv file

Tags: php, logging, csv, zip, extract

I need a php script that extracts a file (with folders and subfolders) and creates a log in which insert some info about files extracted.

Now the script below extracts a zip file (with folders and subfolders) but inserts only last file extracted info in the csv files. How can i fix it to create a list of all files extracted info.

Thanks for help.

```
file = "test.zip";
$dir = getcwd();
function Unzip($dir, $file, $destiny="")
{
$dir .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$path_file = $dir . $file;
$zip = zip_open($path_file);
$_tmp = array();
$count=0;
if ($zip)
{
    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
    {
        $_tmp[$count]["filename"] = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
        $_tmp[$count]["stored_filename"] = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
        $_tmp[$count]["size"] = zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry);
        $_tmp[$count]["compressed_size"] = zip_entry_compressedsize($zip_entry);
        $_tmp[$count]["mtime"] = "";
        $_tmp[$count]["comment"] = "";
        $_tmp[$count]["folder"] = dirname(zip_entry_name($zip_entry));
        $_tmp[$count]["index"] = $count;
        $_tmp[$count]["status"] = "ok";
        $_tmp[$count]["method"] = zip_entry_compressionmethod($zip_entry);

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r"))
        {
            $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
            if($destiny)
            {
                $path_file = str_replace("/",DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $destiny . zip_entry_name($zip_entry));
            }
            else
            {
                $path_file = str_replace("/",DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $dir . zip_entry_name($zip_entry));
            }
            $new_dir = dirname($path_file);

            mkdir($new_dir);

            $fp = fopen($dir . zip_entry_name($zip_entry), "w");
            fwrite($fp, $buf);
            fclose($fp);

            zip_entry_close($zip_entry);

        }
        echo "\n</pre>";
        $count++;
        $named = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);                            
        $outputfile = "log.csv";
        if (!$outfilefp = fopen($outputfile, "w"))
        die("<br>No write on $outputfile");
        else
        echo "<br>Add lines to csv file";
        $temp = array($path_file,$new_dir,$named);
        fputcsv($outfilefp, $temp, ";");
    }

    zip_close($zip);
}
}
  Unzip($dir,$file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is inserting every one, but you are overwriting the last inserted file each time, so you only see the last one. The mode for [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) should be **a** not **w**

> 'w'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of
>   the file and **truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not
>   exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'a'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the
>   file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.